# How can play the background sound on react native expo project via expo-av?

Tags: react-native, audio, expo

I'd like play background sound on react-native expo project.
For this I used the `expo-av`library.
But I could not reproduce it and I got some error.

Error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Cannot load an AV asset from a null playback source]

Stack trace:
  node_modules\expo-av\build\AV.js:115:14 in getNativeSourceAndFullInitialStatusForLoadAsync$
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:170:17 in <unknown>
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:23 in doResolve
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:12 in Promise
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:169:27 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:216:8 in async
  node_modules\expo-av\build\AV.js:88:7 in getNativeSourceAndFullInitialStatusForLoadAsync
  node_modules\expo-av\build\Audio\Sound.js:89:111 in loadAsync$
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:271:30 in invoke
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:45:44 in tryCatch
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:135:28 in invoke
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:170:17 in <unknown>
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:45:7 in tryCallTwo
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:200:23 in doResolve
  node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:66:12 in Promise
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:169:27 in callInvokeWithMethodAndArg
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:192:38 in enqueue
  node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:216:8 in async
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkU9z.png)
This is my snack code. https://snack.expo.io/@milutin/58ff49.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you were doing wrong was passing a sound file to the `uri` property which was expecting a `URL` to the file, not the file itself.

So all you need to do is remove the object you were passing as the first argument and replace it with just the `require` statement.

```
const playbackObject = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
  require('./assets/countDown.mp3'),
  { shouldPlay: true }
);

playbackObject.playAsync();
```

Here's a running [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@fayeed/58ff49)